# Appending asterisks to required fields when validation is conditional

Tags: jquery, validation, conditional-statements

I have conditional validation and want to append an asterisk to the fields that are required. I could easily do this if i specify the class "required" to the fields however i am specifying the requireds using Rules, as some of the validation rules are conditional.

For example, i have 3 radio buttons: (Home Tel, Work Tel, Cell) and 3 corresponding fields that are required depending on which radio is selected.

I want to be able to append an asterisk initially to Home Tel field, however if Work Tel radio is selected then i want the Work Tel field to have the asterisk instead of the Home Tel as Work Tel becomes required and not Home Tel.

Below is my conditions:

```
hphone: { required: function(element){ return $('#phonePref:checked').val() == 0; } },
cPhone: { required: function(element){ return $('#phonePref:checked').val() == 2; } },
wphone: { required: function(element){ return $('#phonePref:checked').val() == 1; } },
```

What is the best way to handle this?

In advance, thanks for your help.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation <-- Take a look here...

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems backwards...

You should be structuring your html to automatically have the * already defined and then after you process for validation then use jquery to identify areas in your html that are required however, have not been filled in, ie your form as defined should require a phone option and the phone selection be a radio list once you select which phone will be primary (ie work phone) then require that particular phone number and set your conditional to it.

Your going backwards to me...

Comment: Hi Joe, 
That is exactly what i am doing. Maybe my explanation sounded backwards but I am doing as you said already. I want the asterisks to display as soon as they get to the page. So in my example above, hphone is required to start off with using the class required.. but if they choose cPhone radio then that field would become required and displaying the asterisk in the place.